# How to keep the color of a dropdown-toggle darker when the cursor is in the dropdown menu in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I asked a detail question previously about this, but I think that was the wrong approach to solve the problem. So I am asking this as simply as possible.

I am using Twitter-Bootstrap and I have set my dropdown-toggle to dropdown on hover (normally it happens through clicking).

During hovering, the dropdown-toggle becomes a darker color to highlight it, however, as the user moves his/her cursor to the dropdown menu, the color of the dropdown-toggle changes back to its original.

How do I fix this? I tried using the active and focus classes but that did not seem to work. Any help is greatly appreciated. I can make a fiddle for you guys if that would help.

Edit: I have figured out the solution thanks to Turbopip. It is something like this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown:active {
    background-color: black;
}
```

After seeing him use the anchor tag for solution two, and dropdowns for 3 and 4, I figured I had to change the color of the dropdown tag, not dropdown-toggle.

Comment: Please post your code here / create a **snippet** or create a **[demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net)**.

Comment: @divy3993- Yes, on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1? Try to set the class of the `<li class="dropdown">` to `open` on hover

Solution 2? This might help, but will know more once you post the code.

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a {
   background-color: black;
}
```

Solution 3? You could also try adding the class `active` to the opened LI, it should create the same effect, and you are already using javascript/jquery to simulate clicks in Bootstrap, I would guess.

Solution 4? In your script that creates the hover effect with Bootstrap CSS, listen to the `li.dropdown` instead of `li.dropdown > a`

Comment: This does not answers the OP's question. Kindly find out what OP really wants and Answer again.

Comment: The menu does open on hover, its just that when the cursor is moved to the dropdown-menu, the dropdown-toggle loses its color and reverts back to its original color, even though the menu remains open.

Comment: @divy3993: I know what (s)he wants, it's just a matter of implementation based on code. And for all I knew, the `open` class could help if it was not set already by his hover-script. So I stand by my first solution based on the info we all had.

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee: Have you tried adding the `open` class with script, can you see that the open class is added on hover?

Comment: @turbopipp Extremely sorry for that comment, i guess you are going the right direction.

Comment: @Turpopipp- I figured out where the problem using your solutions. Thank you!

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee: Great! :) Your welcome. Mind sharing what the solution actually was?

Comment: @turbopipp: Absolutely dont mind. I updated my first post with the solution.